# Sencha Touch List Component

Tags: list, templates, function, sencha-touch, extjs

I have 2 questions. First, is this possible to use List item in sencha touch without template? I mean, can i access the list item seperately?

The second one is related with the first one. I need to send my store item in template as a function parametere how can i do this? I tried below but does not work.

```
template = new Ext.XTemplate(
'<div style="width:100%;height:40px;">',
'<span>{c}</span><span style="font-size:10px" >{e}</span>',
'<span>           ',
'<tpl for=".">',
        '<span onload="formatNumber({i})">{i}</span>',
'</tpl></span>',
'</div>',
{
```

Thanks,

Comment: I have found the answer right after i sent the message. We can access the store item with values.item 

    '<span>{[this.formatNumber(values.i)]} </span>',

Comment: But still i need answer for my first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list items' HTML is in the property `all.elements`. That will give you the HTML DOM node of each item in the list.  The property isn't public so it may break in a future version.

I don't really understand what you are trying to do.  You can render anything with a template.

Comment: I try to render using my own function. Does the list item have an property for that?